# Confusing Error from type matching (I think) - Haskell

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

Getting an error I just can't make sence of

Basically my program is supposed to preform operations on a custom data type 'Config'

```
type Vname = String
type Val = Int
type State = [(Vname, Val)]

data Instr =
        LOADI Int
        | LOAD Val
        | ADD
        | STORE Val
        | JMP Int
        | JMPLESS Int
        | JMPGE Int
        deriving (Eq, Read, Show)

data Stack = Stack [Int]
type Config = (Int, State, Stack)

iexec :: Instr -> Config -> Config
iexec (LOADI n) c = do {
        (x,y,z) <- c 
        ;return ( x+1, y, x )
}
```

I've only tried to implement one of the instructions 'LOADI' but no matter what I seem to change I get the error:

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘Stack’
                  with actual type ‘(c1, b0, c0)’
    • In the pattern: (x, y, z)
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: (x, y, z) <- c
      In the expression:
        do (x, y, z) <- c
           return (x + 1, y, x)
   |
42 |         (x,y,z) <- c 
   |         ^^^^^^^
```

Stack is just a list of Int's but I have to implement it this way

What is (c1, b0, c0) and why doesn't my third value of the config tuple work the same as the others?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Joe

Comment: Your issue is using do notation but not actually using a monad.  Do you understand `do ...` vs `let ... in ...`?

Comment: You are using monadic `do` notation, but your types are not involving any monad. Solution: don't use `do`, don't use `return`, and any other monad-related stuff. For instance, `iexec (LOADI n) (x,y,z) =(x+1,y,z)` type checks and is close to your code. (I don't think it's what you really need, though)

Comment: What makes it all the more confusing is that `(Int, State, Stack)` *has* a `Monad` instance, one that makes `s <- c` be a way of extracting the stack component of the tuple.

Comment: @chepner Good point, but I think that fails because `Int` is not a monoid. This does not help generating a good error message.

Comment: Yeah, the failure to match a `Stack` against `(x, y, z)` just happens first, so that's where you get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
iexec :: Instr -> Config -> Config
```

Ok, so `iexec` takes two arguments and returns a `Config` (a tuple).

```
iexec (LOADI n) c = do
```

Oh, but this says `iexec` takes two arguments and returns something in the form `Monad m => m a`  (usually IO for beginners but not always).

You don't want `do` notation here - you're not making a monadic operation at all, just a pure non-monadic computation. For this you should use `let ... in ...` if you need intermediate values or just the resulting expression if not:

```
iexec :: Instr -> Config -> Config
iexec (LOADI n) (x,y,z) = (x+1, y, x)
```

Or consider the equivalent:

```
iexec :: Instr -> Config -> Config
iexec (LOADI n) (x,y,z) =
    let newPC = x+1
        newState = y
        newStack = x
    in (newPC, newState, newStack)
```

No of course that `newStack` value being `x` isn't going to work at all because a Stack is not an `Int`, but that's just matching your original code.